# Is it true that Googlebot doesn't wait for AJAX requests to complete?

Tags: seo

This article suggests that Googlebot downloads and executes javascript files in  tags on the page, but doesn’t wait for the completion of AJAX calls for additional Javascript/HTML fragments/data:

http://www.analog-ni.co/precomposing-a-spa-may-become-the-holy-grail-to-seo

Has anyone else found this to be the case? Have things evolved since it was posted in January 2015?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion contradicts what has been said by John Mueller from Google in his webmaster videos. Google does a good effort to analyze and understand what users put in their pages with Javascript. It will wait for Ajax answers (but not indefinitely of course).

Answer (score -1):

Google does load ajax, and waits for up to 10 seconds for all ajax calls to complete.

Articles on the topic:
https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/122/does-google-execute-javascript